# is possible restore a package which was REMOVED when run an apt-get install

Tags: server, apt, uninstall

I'm having a really bad time by my noob knowledge about linux, I run

sudo apt-get install but seems than the repository package collide with some other important package in my server...so in this text when I run

```
 sudo apt-get install <some package>



The following packages will be REMOVED:
...... <SOME IMPORTANT PACKAGE>
```

now, would be possible roll back this installation and restore SOME IMPORTANT PACKAGE ???

Notice: I tried reinstall the important package using apt-get but seems not exist in the repository, maybe because it was installed by my hosting service

Notice 2: the important package is plesk core...

thank you so much

Comment: https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/213367169-Unable-to-upgrade-install-Plesk-package-it-is-not-installable

Comment: It means that this package is somehow in conflict with what you installed and can not exist on the same server as your newly installed package.